# WPF Combobox floating watermark - MetroStyle

Tags: c#, wpf, combobox, mahapps.metro

I have some TextBoxes using floating watermark like this:

```
<TextBox x:Name="cbCombo" mah:TextBoxHelper.Watermark="Some watermark"
mah:TextBoxHelper.UseFloatingWatermark="True" Text="{Binding Path=Prop.name}" 
IsEnabled="False"></TextBox>
```

And they work as intended. But I have a problem with ComboBox - the same settings (UseFloatingWatermark, Watermark) that sets up floating watermark are not working at all:

```
<ComboBox mah:TextBoxHelper.Watermark="Receiver"
mah:TextBoxHelper.UseFloatingWatermark="True" x:Name="cbNotWorking"
VerticalAlignment="Top" Margin="{StaticResource MainMargin}"  
ItemsSource="{Binding SomeCollection}" DisplayMemberPath="Name"
SelectedValuePath="Id" />
```

ComboBox above does not work. It shows watermark at the beginning but not after item selection (at the left-top corner of ComboBox). I searched for an answer at the MahApps gitter room and they told me that it is possible to accomplish this.

I tried it with nuGet package, and source from github (it seems to be different).

Comment: The floating watermark for Combobox is currently only available if it's editable. You can create an issue at Github for this.

Comment: @punker76, thanks, I will. This is a must-have feature for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MahApps now has floating watermark support for ComboBox and DateTimePicker, thanks to punker76 (pre-release 1.3.0).